# Use Marvell 88SE9172 sata controller for HW RAID 1

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive, raid, mdadm

I setup a hardware RAID 1 with a **Marvell 88SE9172 sata controller** on a **GA-Z97X-Gaming 7** motherboard.

In my BIOS all settings seem fine and the RAID 1 was setup using the post boot setup. Unfortunately the drives are still shown as two separate drives in the Ubuntu disk manager.

[image: One RAID member shown in the Ubuntu disk manager]

How can I combine both RAID members to be a real hardware RAID 1?